# Redis : Querying based on matching key pattren

Tags: redis

I am new to Redis I tried to figure out this problem going through Redis documentation but no luck. Here are the details.

Lets say I inserted Strings like below.

```
Set category:1 "Men"
Set category:2 "Women"
Set category:3 "Kids"
Set category:4 "Home"
Set category:5 "shoes" ...
```

Now I want to get all the values by querying with keys which follow certain pattern in this case `category:*`.

```
Get category:*
```

Is there any way to get all categories like this?

Comment: Use KEYS category:* to get all the keys and then extract all the values by iterating over them. You may get all the values in a single call by using MGET

Comment: While technically correct, **DO NOT** use `KEYS` in production

Answer (score 2):

Use [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan). SCAN is the only safe way to iterate through the keys in a Redis database. SCAN will chunk out a portion of the keyspace and return a cursor (always the first result) and any values it found in that chunk. You start with a cursor of 0.

```
> SCAN 0 MATCH "category:*"
1) "1904"
2) (empty list or set)
```

Then you pass that cursor back into the SCAN command with the same pattern:

```
> SCAN 1904 MATCH "category:*"
1) "0"
2) 1) "category:3"
   2) "category:2"
   3) "category:4"
   4) "category:1"
```

In this case the cursor returned is 0 which is the signal that the SCAN command has completed. The second response is an array with the keys found. Note that you need to run the SCAN command in a loop and none or only part of keys that match the pattern will be returned each time.

After you get the keys, you'll need to retrieve the values as normal (GET).

*Just a note*: From the look of how your data is structured, you're likely using an inappropriate data type: The categories would be better organized into a hash (e.g. `HSET categories 1 men` then you can use `HGETALL`)

Comment: Thanks @stockholmux, the data structure I provided is just a sample, the actual value is JSON with all the details of that category.

Comment: @krishna_5c3 You should definitely look at [ReJSON](http://rejson.io/) then  and specifically `JSON.OBJKEYS`. It will make your life much easier

Comment: I don't know about ReJSON until now. Thanks @stockholmux I will use it in my project.